# Why the below function is not returning any value and it is always returns empty

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my program to get the random number from the function called 'RandomNum'

```
Sub Test()

Dim RandomNo As Variant

RandomNo = RandomNum(RandomNo)
Range("B6").Value = RandomNo

End Sub
```

Below is the code for the function called 'RandomNum' and it is used to create a 8-digit random alpha numeric text. It always returns an empty value to the main function

```
Public Function RandomNum(RandomNo As Variant) As Variant

alphaNumericText = UCase("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")
alphaText = UCase("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

RandomNo = ""
Randomize
For i = 1 To 8
    RandomNo = RandomNo & Mid$(alphaNumericText, Int(Rnd() * Len(alphaNumericText) + 1), 1)
Next

End Function
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through it? Why do you bother passing `RandomNo` to your function if the first thing you do with it is set it to `""`?

Comment: Your function doesn't *return* a value, so in Test `RandomNo` always get nothing assigned to it.  you need to decide if you want to get the value via a ByRef parameter, or via a return value - right now you're sort of doing both...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would re-write like this so that the function *returns* the random alpha-numeric `String`; there's no need to try to pass a `ByRef` parameter:

```
Public Function RandomAlphaNumeric() As String
    Dim alphaNumericText As String
    alphaNumericText = UCase("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")

    Randomize
    For i = 1 To 8
        RandomAlphaNumeric = RandomAlphaNumeric & Mid$(alphaNumericText, Int(Rnd() * Len(alphaNumericText) + 1), 1)
    Next
End Function

Sub Test()
    Range("B6").Value = RandomAlphaNumeric
End Sub
```

You could even add functionality to pass in an optional *length* parameter instead of hard-coding the `8`.