# Evaluate Using Wrong Worksheet and Errors

Tags: excel, vba

First, a little preface.

Im still a little new to VBA. I was attempting to write code for a random number generator. 8 digit, alphanumeric. I accomplished this by having one sheet where the number would be pasted (List) and another sheet that is hidden where the number is created (Generator). On the Generator sheet in column B I put A-Z and 0-9 and then in A1 had this formula concatenated together 8 times: `INDEX(B:B,RANDBETWEEN(1,36))`

This worked very well. I then wrote a little code to handle repeats and then paste the result in the first empty cell in B:B on the List sheet.

But I wanted to get a little more creative, and I didn't want to have to change the index part of the formula 8 times if I wanted to add lowercase or special characters later on. I wanted to be able to change it in one spot and then the rest of them follow suit. So with concatenate I had a cell which has this text as the value: CONCATENATE(INDEX(B:B,RANDBETWEEN(1,36)),etc...

I then used `Evaluate` in VBA in order to process this as a formula. When I printed this in the immediate window it worked fine. So I ran the code. But it would not work. Finally realized that it was looking on the List sheet for `INDEX(B:B` since it is the first tab. So then I added `Worksheets("Generator").Activate` in the hopes it would look at the proper sheet. Didn't change anything.

Then I researched a little and tried using `Worksheet.Evaluate()` thinking that would do the trick. But then I got either #VALUE! errors or type mismatch errors.

Even still, when trying either `Application.Evaluate()` and specifying the worksheet, or `Worksheet.Evaluate()` in the immediate window before debugging, both options will work how I want them to. But when running the code, or trying the immediate window after starting debugging, the code won't run properly.

Here is the actual code:

```
Dim strRandNum As String
Dim lgLastRow As Long
Dim intCounter As Integer

lgLastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("List").Range("B:B"))
intCounter = 0

TryAgain:

Worksheets("Generator").Activate
' Original: strRandNum = Evaluate(Worksheets("Generator").Range("C1").Value)
strRandNum = Worksheets("Generator").Evaluate(Range("C1").Value)
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("List").Range("B:B"), strRandNum) > 0 Then
    Calculate
    intCounter = intCounter + 1
    If intCounter = 5 Then
        MsgBox ("An error has ocurred. Contact your developer.")
       Exit Sub
    Else
    GoTo TryAgain
    End If
Else
End If

Worksheets("List").Range("B" & lgLastRow + 1).Value = strRandNum
Worksheets("List").Range("B1").Select
```

Comment: I'd just create your own UDF to create a random alphanumeric... this seems like an X-Y problem.

Comment: For reference, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741049/why-the-below-function-is-not-returning-any-value-and-it-is-always-returns-empty) with one recently. It even is already hard-coded to return a string with length of 8 :-)

Comment: Wouldn't `strRangNum = Worksheets("Generator").Range("C1").Value` work?

Comment: Another reason to create a UDF - the use of `GoTo` to loop here is frowned upon.

Comment: @BruceWayne No. All that is in C1 is the formula as text. See the bottom of my third paragraph up top. It needs to be evaluated.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for your response. I will look into that. I am still interested though in why the `evaluate ()` is persistent in looking at the wrong sheet. I even made a new workbook with the generator sheet as the first sheet, and it still looked into the List sheet when returning `INDEX(B:B...`

Comment: @BigBen I looked at the link you provided and it was very helpful for me. I do have a question. In the code I see `Mid$`. What is the reason for the `$`? I ran the code with and without it and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: `Mid$` returns a `String`. `Mid` returns a `Variant/String`.

Comment: Gotcha. And again, a little new to this. So what is the significance of that?

Comment: Without getting into the nitty gritty - either one will work here but I'd prefer `Mid$` over `Mid`.